# sort points by distance to specific point

Tags: sorting, c++11

I try to sort lots of points by distance to a specific point.
So, I decide to use std::sort, but i can't find the way to give Comp function 3rd argument.
I imagine lambda function in Python like `lambda pnt1, pnt2: compare(pnt1, pnt2, myPoint)` but I can't find it.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999471/920069

Comment: Googling "std::sort predicate example" finds any number of examples.

Comment: I am not familiar with c++ syntax. All of yours are useful to me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
int distance(Point const&, Point const&); // Returns distance between points.

Point p{x, y};
std::vector<Point> points{...};
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [p](Point const& a, Point const& b) {
    return distance(a, p) < distance(b, p);
});
```